# C# regex end of string

Tags: c#, regex

I tried to make something work that I found on msdn and was looking for some help. Im trying to find where there is an (asterisk, wildcard, star) which will be at the end of the string, and return that match. Where did I go wrong with my pattern?

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string pattern;
        pattern = ("*$");
        Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

        string[] tests =
        {
            "42", ".45", "3452013232", "2015550777*"
        };

        foreach (string test in tests)
        {
          if(rgx.IsMatch(test))
            Console.WriteLine(test);
          else 
            Console.WriteLine("No Matches!");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you just use `string.EndsWith()`

Comment: why don't you use the `.Contains() method and or the IndexOf` to determine the end of the string...? or `EndsWIth()`

Comment: I have to use regex because its part of a bigger project which I am not in control of, my boss is.

Comment: in regex, the `*` character has a special meaning.  If you want to test if a string ends with an actual `*`, you need to escape it.

Comment: thats a backslash correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asterisk has a special meaning in a regular expression. If you want to match an actual asterisk you have to escape it. Try:

```
pattern = @"\*$"
```

Comment: Thanks, that returned all the strings in the tests array.